# Why do I get this error in SQL Server? How to fix it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure to insert to a table. Following would provide my table columns are

```
Create Table Item 
(
    ID char(20),
    Name varchar(max) NOT NULL,
    Brand char(10) NOT NULL,
    Category char(10) NOT NULL,
    Unit_Of_Measure char(5) NOT NULL,
    Price decimal(18,2) NOT NULL,
    [Image] image NOT NULL,
    Active bit NOT NULL Default('True')

    Constraint PK_Item Primary Key (ID),
    Constraint FK_Item_Brands Foreign Key (Brand) References Brands(ID),
    Constraint FK_Item_Item_Category Foreign Key (Category) References Item_Category(ID),
    Constraint FK_Item_Unit_Of_Measure Foreign Key (Unit_Of_Measure) References Unit_Of_Measure(ID)
);
go
```

Table insert is working fine. Before we go further I need to show the error that I am getting.

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 2, Procedure stpItem, Line 66
>   Operand type clash: image is incompatible with nvarchar

The above error occurs when I'm executing the command below and after that you would see the stored procedure

```
exec stpItem '','GG','2','2','2',123.12, null, 'true', 'false'
```

Stored procedure code:

```
Create Proc stpItem
    @ID varchar(max),
    @Name varchar(max),
    @Brand varchar(max),
    @Category varchar(max),
    @UOM varchar(max),
    @Price decimal,
    @Image Image,
    @Active bit,
    @Update bit
As
   Set Transaction Isolation Level Serializable
   Begin Transaction
   Begin Try

-- If it is an insertion
IF @Update = 'False' 
Begin

Declare @Pre char(1),
        @Len int,
        @Next int,
        @Start int,
        @SetKey varchar(max);

Set @SetKey = '';
Select @Pre = Prefix, @Len = [Length], @Next = [Next] From Key_Generation Where Table_Name = 'Item';
Set @Start = 1;
Set @Len = @Len - 1;
While @Start < @Len
Begin
set @SetKey = @SetKey + '0'
set @Start = @Start + 1;
End

Exec('Declare @LID char(20); Set @LID =  (select ''' + @Pre + ''' + right(''' + @SetKey + ''' + cast(' + @Next + ' as varchar(' + @Len + ')), ' + @Len + '));' +
'Insert into Item Values (@LID,''' + @Name + ''',''' + @Brand + ''',''' + @Category + ''',''' + @UOM + ''',' + @Price + ',' + @Image + ' ,' + @Active + ');' + 
'Update Key_Generation Set [Next] = [Next] + 1 Where Table_Name = ''Item'';');

End
Else
Begin

   Update Item 
   Set Name = @Name, 
       [Brand] = @Brand, 
       [Category] = @Category, 
       [Unit_Of_Measure] = @UOM, 
       Price = @Price, 
       [Image] = @Image, 
       Active = @Active 
   Where ID = @ID;
End

Commit Transaction;
End Try
Begin Catch
    Rollback Transaction;

    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

    SELECT 
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

    -- Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return error
    -- information about the original error that caused
    -- execution to jump to the CATCH block.
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
               @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
               @ErrorState -- State.
               );
End Catch
```

Could anyone tell me why I am getting this error, and how to fix this issue?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: If you have declared @image as not null, then why do you give a null value to it? And as a second thing, instead of image, try `varchar(max)` or `varbinary(max)`

Comment: Ange1 it just to try that works or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are not casting non varchar variables to varchar here:

```
 @Price + ',' + @Image + ' ,' + @Active + ');'
```

Try:

```
 cast(@price as varchar(max)) + ',' + cast(@image as varchar(max)) + ...
```

Comment: Did you just copy pasted? Just replace `@price with cast(@price as varchar(max))`, replace `@image with cast(@image as varchar(max))` etc in your exec

Comment: Then try to add some quote around image

Comment: Instead of exec do a print and see what statement is generated.

Comment: Wasnt this answer a little bit helpful at all?

Answer (score 0):

```
cast(cast(@Image as binary) as nvarchar(max));
```

I used a nvarchar variable to convert it from outside then use it inside og execution command

```
Declare @txtImage nvarchar(max);
if @Image IS NULL
Begin Set @txtImage = 'NULL'; END
Else
Begin Set @txtImage = cast(cast(@Image as binary) as nvarchar(max)); END
```